# Hiding reputation

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, reputation

In MathOverflow 1.0 we had the ability to hide other users' reputations.  Can we get that again?

(Also, I had to rewrite this question several times to get past an annoying box that said my question didn't meet "quality standards" and suggested I needed to check my grammar.  Is there any way to make it be more informative about what its problem is?  I suspect it was only upset that my original version was too short before I added all this parenthetical irrelevancy.)

Comment: You can use these user scripts:

http://stackapps.com/questions/2342/hexadecimal-user-rep

Comment: About your other question: you can find some pointers and basic information about quality filter [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/quality-filter/info) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92074/what-can-i-do-when-getting-it-does-not-meet-our-quality-standards).

Comment: Something similar was asked in this post (and some of the linked posts) at meta.SO: [Hide the rep and badge count on a user's info box on answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21458/hide-the-rep-and-badge-count-on-a-users-info-box-on-answers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has now been implemented on the main site (and not here on Meta): see the announcement at [Viewing reputation and badges is now opt-in and compatible with the new front page](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/5218) for further details.

It works as follows. Anywhere on the main site, click on the "Achievements" icon in the top bar, and click on the "hide rep" link at the top right corner of the dropdown menu. Doing so will hide reputation points everywhere, and this link will toggle to now read "show rep". Clicking it once more will make reputation points visible everywhere once again.

Just to emphasize, you will not find this option here on Meta. It is currently enabled only on the main site.

If you are hiding reputation points with this feature, and want to check a user's reputation but don't want to use the toggle, then you will need to navigate to that user's profile (which can be done by clicking on that user's username) to do so.

Here is a screenshot from the linked announcement showing what the toggle item looks like in the dropdown menu:

[image]

Comment: Maybe it is worth mentioning that this wasn't implemented by Stack Exchange - it is a script maintained by MathOverflow moderators. (The [agreement between MO and SE](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/4429) explicitly allows the mods of MO add some JavaScript code specifically for this site.)

Answer (score 3):

Tim has just told us the Stack Exchange folks aren't going to implement this. I think that the userscripts linked are probably sufficient. The alternative, if they aren't sufficient, is for us to implement some custom javascript on MathOverflow that 'hacks' this option back in. (This is effectively how we'd done this on 1.0.)

However this will take some amount of work. I'm personally not that excited about doing it, but if someone makes a new feature request "Implement reputation hiding in custom javascript", it gets voted up a bunch, and no one else jumps in to offer to do it, I'll put it on my todo list. (A lame promise, I realise!)

Answer (score 2):

Isn't this easy to do with custom css?

```
span.reputation-score, span.badgecount, span.badge1, span.badge2 {
    display: none;
}
```

The above works pretty well for me, but I'm sure it could be refined into something better.

And for the record, I myself have no objections to seeing users' reputation scores.

---

I haven't tested it, but using AdBlock would be another solution, I think.  Control-or-right-click on objectionable thing, then "block this ad", then...

Comment: [Stylebot](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylebot/oiaejidbmkiecgbjeifoejpgmdaleoha), a Chrome extension, also works very well for this sort of thing. Right click whatever you want to remove, select Stylebot, Style Element and then set "Visibility" to "Hide", or whatever else you want.

Comment: For me (in Chrome), AdBlock works slightly differently: I don't have a context menu option to block an ad, but there's an icon in the address bar for AdBlock, and clicking on it gives the option "Easy create filter", after which you can just point at what you want to remove.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, no, no such means exist in the current platform and is unlikely to be implemented. It's not that this is an unpopular idea, a few folks in various communities have expressed interest in removing some of the 'game' aspect from participation, but it's not something that we're likely to do, quite a bit revolves around that number.

What I recommend you do is just use one of the available userscripts (as linked in comments) to take care of this for you, and even modify them to suit your needs if you're able to do so.

Comment: I understand that quite a lot revolves around that number, and I don't necessarily disagree with that aspect of the way the sites work -- internally.  What I don't like (and I know some other people don't like) is how prominently displayed that number is, to the extent that you almost never see a user's name without it.