# Reputation displays after an edit even if opted out

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, editing

I mentioned this in a [comment](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/5218/viewing-reputation-and-badges-is-now-opt-in#comment26853_5218) on the [main announcement](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/5218/viewing-reputation-and-badges-is-now-opt-in) regarding not automatically displaying reputation, but perhaps it is worth making into a formal bug report.

After I edit a post, reputation is displayed again, even if I have opted out of it.  This only happens on the post that is edited, and only immediately after the edit; refreshing reverts to not displaying the reputation.

Comment: I will look further into this. I admit that of all the other things, I did not test how edits (and "soft reloads") interact with the script.

Comment: Just as an update, I have fixed the problem, but with the new page rollout (which I've also fixed), I think it's probably wise to give it a few more days for SE to settle down before making updates to the script. I don't want it to break *again* over some follow-up change.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, [that](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/5225/reputation-displays-after-an-edit-even-if-opted-out#comment26886_5225) means that it is expected behaviour that I am currently still seeing the issue, right?

Comment: Yes. That means that we still haven't rolled out the fix, and it may take a few more days. Honestly, if I had known about the new page design, I would have delayed the deployment of the original script a bit longer. But, it is what it is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We rolled out the fix.

Thank you for noticing that bug.