# Badges appear to have disappeared

Tags: bug, mathjax, badges

It looks like badges are no longer showing on users when browsing questions/answers:

[image: A screenshot of a MO answer, there are no badges shown below the answer's author's user card]

The badges appear while the pages loads, but as soon as the mathjax fully loads, they disappear. Checking other SE sites, it appears to only happen here; I can't reproduce on other sites. It seems to affect both questions and answers.

Has been [reproed by 2 other users](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/60298442#60298442). I'm on Windows 10, using Chrome, with no userscripts active.

Comment: There was this recent announcement: [Viewing reputation and badges is now opt-in](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/5218) And this post a bit before that: [Reputation and badges are no longer visible next to the users' names](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/5209). IIRC at the time of the announcement, the badges were hidden in the list of the question, but still shown when displaying a question. Let's hope we'll hear from the mods whether the change was intentional.

Comment: @MartinSleziak Given that a mod has answered the second, and posted the first, I'll assume it's an intentional change - either way, I;ve flagged this as a duplicate of the second

Comment: [Reputation and badges are no longer visible next to the users' names](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/5209) - now that I looked in the screenshot here, it seems that it was hidden from the start in both places. So I remembered it incorrectly.