# Where did the reputation go?

Tags: discussion, bug, status-norepro, reputation

Some time ago, it was decided that reputation should no longer be displayed by default, but users had the possibility to opt in to see it, [as explained by Ben Webster](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/5218). I had opted to see reputation, but today I have just noticed that it is gone! Gone is also the "show rep" link in the achievements menu. Are the moderators making changes to the site [again without consulting with and informing the community](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/5209/reputation-and-badges-are-no-longer-visible-next-to-the-users-names#comment26733_5211)?

(It is interesting to remark that even the most open and democratic people tend to become dictatorial when they get into positions of power.)

Comment: Or, maybe, you cleared your cache? It's a client-side script, it's not an option that is saved on the SE servers. (The insinuation of dictatorship is uncalled for, frankly quite very rude.)

Comment: Also, sometimes StackExchange makes changes to the software outside the control of the mods, but as I am new to the gig, I haven't seen anything like this yet.

Answer (score 13):

StackExchange is constantly evolving. Since the script is maintained by the moderators, and we are not notified in advance about these changes, we have no choice but to be reactive.

Changes happen, users point out the script is broken, we fix it, they publish the new script.

Insinuations of dictatorship are not helpful to anyone. I understand that you are angry that you're unable to view some numbers on the internet, it is a mathematics website, but assuming some sort of malicious cabal is toying with you, rather than the updates to the user interface (which you may have noticed, being perceptive enough to notice the lack of reputation) breaking parts of the script.

I will update when I have fixed the problem. In the meantime, try to make the most of not seeing people through the lens of their reputation.

Comment: So there is actually some problem? Things are displayed normally to me, as shown in the screenshot [posted in the MO chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/9369/2022/10/29).

Comment: Your sarcasm is not justified. It happened several times that the SE staff or the MO moderators made changes without consulting with the whole community, which resulted in a bit of voiced frustration. Since humans reason by analogy and induction, I simply imagined that this was yet another case of such behaviour. If this change is indeed caused by the SE staff making changes and not caring about properly publicizing them, this only supports my remark that even nice people who get at the top stop caring about those at the bottom.

Comment: @MartinSleziak: Weird, it seems to affect users non-uniformly.

Comment: @AlexM. It is my dictatorial privilege, apparently. Nobody said you can't criticise people, or complain about changes.

Comment: @Alex StackExchange the company (or is it StackOverflow?) has a history of rolling out changes in a way the overall community hasn't appreciated, and this has been the case for years. It's a company that provides a service that sometimes makes bad calls on product roll-out. It's not elected people going mad with power, but chains of managers trying to balance the needs of their user base and the internal demands of people higher up. Sometimes these effects are emergent, and not the result of one person's decision, like many things in the world.

Comment: @Martin: It's working fine on my phone, not so much in my laptop

Comment: So now that at least one other person confirmed that there is a problem, maybe the tag ([meta-tag:bug]) could be added to the question? I guess now it can be considered a bug report.

Comment: @MartinSleziak: Bug reports normally contain bug reports, rather than annoyed complaints. I have little to work with. What browser, OS, any js blocking add-ons, if any, are being used? Which platform is the site accessed from?

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Firefox 106.0.2, Windows 10 Home 21H2 64bit. The bug also shows up when using Firefox in troubleshoot mode or with a new user profile, so it cannot be caused by extensions or user-preferences.

Comment: I agree it must be patchy. I can see rep fine on Firefox on Mac and also Android.

Comment: @Alex: Logged out users will not have the option to opt-in for reputation. Just in case you were in that situation.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Hmm, maybe this is it. I did not log out, but I did "refresh" my Firefox (this is the Firefox term) in the hope of getting rid of what turned out to be a bug. In conclusion, if one logs out and then logs back in to MO, one can no longer see reputation? Strange.

Comment: @AlexM. In the meantime, my "show rep" is back.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: The oddity is that the problem does not manifest itself on Meta.MO. Also, my "show rep" is still missing, unlike yours.

Comment: @AlexM. IIRC hiding rep was never applied on meta - only on the main site. At the time it was mentioned, for example, [in this comment](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/26850). (And maybe in some other places, too - but this is what I was able to find quickly.)

Comment: @AsafKaragila: "show rep" is back for me too, and working properly, thank you. What was the cause of the malfunction (if not too technical to discuss here)?

Comment: @AlexM.: I have only just got back home, I did nothing. So, I don't know.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Oh, then let me quickly retract the above thanks.

Comment: @AlexM.: Come on, relax. Two people out there are doing their best to understand the problem and help, even though you called them dictatorial. So would it not be better to retract the above *accusations* rather than *thanks*?

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki: It is tiresome to have to put smileys in every text that is meant to be taken as a joke; I trust this community to be able to tell joke from offense. But here, let me explicit for you: of course that I was not retracting thanks. We should also not let this stream of comments get longer that it is useful.