# Could MO use a minus sign for negative numbers?

Tags: feature-request, design

I just noticed that negative vote totals are recorded with a hyphen:

[image: -1 votes]

In general within the StackExchange network it's probably not worth fussing over, but, here on MO, maybe we could use a minus sign (that is, "−1 votes", as opposed to "-1 votes").  Is this something that is within the power of MO to do, if we choose?  (I know that up- and down-vote arrows can be customised, but I don't know about vote totals.)  If it is within our power, is it something that the community wants to do?

Comment: This seems pettifogging to me.

Comment: It is certainly not a high priority, but, if not in a community of mathematicians, then where else should one care for using good notation to maintain subtle but meaningful distinctions?

Comment: This has been suggested a few times in the past, and either declined or ignored by the devs: see e.g. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124216/replace-hyphen-in-front-of-scores-reputation-by-minus , https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/364274/vote-count-minus-signs-not-readable-in-segoe-ui .

Comment: Btw, up and down arrows cannot be customized any longer. The devs are trying hard to get rid of as many exceptions as they can.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek, thank you for [this](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/30717) and [that](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/30718) information. (I would be fine with closing as duplicate, except that my understanding is that we don't do cross-site duplicate closures.) Of course the point of democratic voting is to discover what people think, not to argue with it, but I'm surprised that a notational proposal that at various times has gathered 37 − 5 and 26 − 3 upvotes on the general SE network should be currently so poorly received here. Nonetheless, I guess it is moot!

Comment: @EmilJeřábek The agreement between MO and SE states that the MO team can customize the look and feel of the site with additional Javascript, as long as the MO team maintains it (point 4 [here](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/a/4430/1898)). This change seems simple enough to do with Javascript, even if the SE developers don't want to implement anything.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni If it’s really that simple, go for it. I know nothing about the capabilitites of Javascript.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek I am not particularly interested in this change myself, or strongly supporting it; I was just pointing out that it is well within the realm of possibility.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Adapted from a [comment](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/5890/could-mo-use-a-minus-sign-for-negative-numbers#comment30749_5890) of mine: yes, it is technically in MO's power.

The agreement between MO and SE states that the MO team can customize the look and feel of the site with additional Javascript, as long as the MO team maintains it (point 4 [here](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/a/4430/1898)).

This change seems simple enough to do with Javascript, even if the SE developers don't want to implement anything.

It is additional burden on the moderators, though, so maybe OP or someone else who is interested in this change can put together the Javascript code to do it.

Another possibility is creating a [userscript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Userscript), so everyone who wants to see true minus signs can install it on their browser and customize the appearance for themselves only. In my opinion it is best to start from this route, creating a userscript and publishing its code here, so that everyone can test the result.

Comment: A userscript for this purpose has been written up by user3840170 in an [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/362147) on Meta SE.